# Sum the counts with Lambda expressions

Tags: vb.net, lambda

I have a `List(of T)` where `T` has a property that is a list of checkboxes, what I need is a Lambda expression that will count all the checked checkboxes in the list.

I tried with:

```
Me.list.Sum(Function(objT) objT.CheckBoxes.Where(Function(chk) chk.Checked).Count)
```

But it didn't do the trick. Any suggestions?

Comment: "it didn't do the trick" what does that mean? Error message or incorrect result? What was the error message / result?

Comment: I was always getting 0 but... now I fixed it and the problem was with the list rather than the lambda. How do I close and discard this question? (At the end the lambda expression works as it should)

Comment: That's what I thought... and why I asked the question. You can't discard the question, what you can do is answer your own question and accept it.

Comment: Oh well.. sorry for all those other answers, I did read them all so it wasn't time wasted guys ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end there was a problem populating the list which translated in an *always 0* answer. Fixing the method that populated the list gave me the correct answer, which means the lambda expression per se was right all along.

**P.S.** sorry for all those other answers, I did read them all so it wasn't time wasted guys ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim count = (From box In objtCheckBoxes Where box.Checked Select box).Count()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim b As New List(Of Boolean)
b.AddRange({True, False, True})
Dim n = b.Sum(Function(x)
                  Return If(x, 1, 0)
              End Function)
```

`n` now contains 2.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow you must tell VB that `T` has a property `CheckBoxes`. Therefore define an interface that the types you add to the list must implement

```
Public Interface ICheckBoxes
    ReadOnly Property CheckBoxes() As List(Of CheckBox)
End Interface

Public Class ClassWithCkeckBoxes
    Implements ICheckBoxes

    Private m_CheckBoxes As List(Of CheckBox) = New List(Of CheckBox)

    Public ReadOnly Property CheckBoxes() As List(Of CheckBox) Implements ICheckBoxes.CheckBoxes
        Get
            Return m_CheckBoxes
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Specify that `T` must implement `ICheckBoxes` with the type parameter `(Of T As ICheckBoxes)`

```
Class CountCheckBoxes(Of T As ICheckBoxes)
    Public Sub Test(ByVal list As List(Of T))
        Dim count As Integer = list _
            .SelectMany(Function(t) t.CheckBoxes) _
            .Count(Function(checkBox) checkBox.Checked)
    End Sub
End Class
```

`SelectMany` flattens the list. I.e., it converts the list of list of checkboxes into a simple list of checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use SelectMany. Something like this may work.

```
Me.list.SelectMany(Function(objT) objT.Checkboxes)
       .Count(Function(chk) chk.Checked)
```